# Invalid credentials on symfony

Tags: symfony

Evening everyone , I've been stack with this problem since few days and whatever I change it remains .. basically on login when I put an invalid email it says email not found , when I put invalid password it says wrong password( I edited it of course ) but when they're both correct it shows Invalid credentials for some reason , I m really disparate .. help me please I can link any page code but Im 90% sure the code is correct ,thanks in advance

SecurityController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('/index');
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

security.yaml

```html
security:
    encoders:
        
        App\Entity\User5:
            algorithm: bcrypt



    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        
        app_user_provider:
              entity:
                  class: 'App\Entity\User5'
                  property: 'email'
                  
      
                      
     

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~

            provider: app_user_provider

            form_login: 
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                    
                    
                
                entry_point: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route
   
            
               
            


            # activate different ways to authenticate

            
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication
            
            # form_login: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    #access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
    # - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

login.html.twig

```html
{% extends 'home.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Log in!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form method="post" action="{{ path('app_login')}}">
    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if app.user %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            You are logged in as {{ app.user.username }}, <a href="{{ path('app_logout') }}">Logout</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" value="{{ last_username }}" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" required>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
           value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
    >

    {#
        Uncomment this section and add a remember_me option below your firewall to activate remember me functionality.
        See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html

        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
    #}

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" >
        Sign in
    </button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

LoginFormAuthenticator

```html
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User5;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;
    private const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User5::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
       
        

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User5::class)->findOneBy(['password' => $credentials['password']]);
        

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Wrong password.');
        }
        

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
        
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('index'));
     
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

User5.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\User5Repository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 * fields={"email"},
 * message="That Email is already taken , try another "
 * )
 */
class User5 implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
 * @ORM\Column(unique=true, type="string", nullable=false)
 */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Role", mappedBy="Users")
     */
    private $userRoles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Role[]
     */
    public function getUserRoles(): Collection
    {
        return $this->userRoles;
    }

    public function addUserRole(Role $userRole): self
    {
        if (!$this->userRoles->contains($userRole)) {
            $this->userRoles[] = $userRole;
            $userRole->addUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUserRole(Role $userRole): self
    {
        if ($this->userRoles->contains($userRole)) {
            $this->userRoles->removeElement($userRole);
            $userRole->removeUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @BahaTh. It will be very difficult for us to help you without code and security configuration I suggest you to edit your question.

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant Thanks a lot , sure I'll try to post code

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this lines, the password is encrypted in the database so you can't retrieve a user by his password, Symfony will do this job (comparing the two passwords).

```
    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User5::class)->findOneBy(['password' => $credentials['password']]);


    if (!$user) {
        // fail authentication with a custom error
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Wrong password.');
    }
```

Comment: I only added that line to see if the problem is from either email or password , so its just optional , and it actually works

Answer (score 0):

I solved it my self , apparently you cant use guard and form login in the same time you gotta pick one of them because both do the same job one is easy and one is customized also I forgot something very important in the register function , forgot to encode the password , now it works just fine

**heres the new register function**

```html
public function register(Request $request , EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {

        $user = new User5();
        
        $form = $this->createForm(Form::class, $user);
        
       $form->handleRequest($request);
       if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $hashed = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());

       $user->setPassword($hashed); 
        
       $entityManager->persist($user);
       $entityManager->flush();

       $this->addFlash("success", "Welcome to our application");

       return $this->redirectToRoute("app_login");  
       
       }
        

        
           
        return $this->render('account/registration.html.twig',[
        'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
            
        
    }
```

new **security.yaml**

```html
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User5:
            algorithm: bcrypt



    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        
        app_user_provider:
              entity:
                  class: 'App\Entity\User5'
                  property: 'email'
                  


    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: app_user_provider

            form_login: 
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                 # default_target_path: dashboard
                 
                    
                
            logout:
                path: logout_user
                target: index
                # target: app_any_route
   
            
               
            


            # activate different ways to authenticate

            
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication
            
            # form_login: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    #access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
    # - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```